# Languages with direct-inverse verbal inflection or hierarchical alignment but no verbal inflection for person

Tags: morphosyntactic-alignment

Some languages have direct-inverse marking on verbs or hierarchical alignment.

I'm wondering whether there are any attested examples of *minimal* direct-inverse systems where the verb is obligatorily marked for *whether* the patient outranks the agent, but not *who the agent and patient actually are*.

As a strawman example, let's take English but add a prefix "ba" that's added when the patient outranks the agent according to the hierarchy `1 > 2 > 3`.

```
I see you.
*I basee you.

*You see me.
 You basee me.
```

---

[Ojibwe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ojibwe) inflects verbs for the person and number of the subject and direct object.

proximate subject and obviative direct object.

```
obizindawaan
o-  bizindaw    -aa -n
3-  listen.to   -DIRECT -3OBVIATIVE
"He listens to the other one"
```

proximate direct object and obviative subject.

```
obizindaagoon
o-  bizindaw    -igoo   -n
3-  listen.to   -INVERSE    -3OBVIATIVE
"The other one listens to him"
```

[Hixkaryana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hixkaryana_language) inflects for the person of the higher ranked core argument of a verb.

```
A-prefixes      O-prefixes
1A   0-/ɨ-      1O      r(o)
2A   m(ɨ)-      2O      o(j)-/a(j)-
1+2A t(ɨ)-      1+2O    k(ɨ)-
3A   n(ɨ)-/j-
```